# Python code seems logically equivalent but one is failing and the other is not

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph

The following is Bellman-Ford's algorithm implemented to find whether there is a negative cycle in the graph or not.
I do not have access to the test cases but there is some edge case that's causing the code to fail when the `dist` array is initialized with `float('inf')`. Why?

```py
def negative_cycle(n, graph):
    # dist = [float('inf')] * (n+1)  (This code fails)
    dist = [1001] * (n+1)          # (this code doesn't)
    dist[1] = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for st, end, cost in graph:
            print(dist)
            if dist[end] > dist[st] + cost:
                dist[end] = dist[st] + cost
                if i == n - 1:
                    return 1
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_vertices, n_edges = map(int, input().split())
    edges = []
    for i in range(n_edges):
        a, b, w = map(int, input().split())
        edges.append((a, b, w)) 
    print(negative_cycle(n_vertices, edges))
```

Comment: `float("inf") == float("inf") + anything`

Comment: the expression `inf + inf results in inf`, but `inf - inf results in NaN` (Not a Number). This can lead to unexpected results in the algorithm.

Comment: Which cases have you tested?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a different output when the input graph has these characteristics:

- Not all nodes are reachable from node 1
- There is a negative cycle between nodes that are not reachable from node 1

In this case the faulty code (with "inf") will report there is no negative cycle, while the correct code will report there is one.

Here is an example input/run of such a case:

```
edges = [
    (1, 2, 0),
    (2, 1, 0),

    (3, 4, -1),
    (4, 3, 0),
    (4, 1, 0)
]
print(negative_cycle(4, edges))
```

Each time the edge with the negative weight is visited, the algorithm will compare `dist[4] > dist[3] - 1`. In the faulty code this expression is `float('inf') > float('inf') - 1` which is False, while in the correct code this expression is `1001 > 1001 - 1` (the first time, then `1000 > 1000 - 1`, ...etc) and so the `if` block gets executed repeatedly, eventually executing `return 1`.

### Remarks

In the correct code it is not necessary to initialise `dist[1]` in a different way than for the other nodes. You could initialise them all with 0. This algorithm doesn't need to have the notion of "I never was here before", which in other algorithms would make it interesting to initialise with `float('inf')`.

Here the only thing that matters is that the algorithm detects that the distance of one or more nodes keeps reducing and never settles to a stable value. For such a detection it doesn't matter at which initial value you start the algorithm with, as long as it is a *finite* value.